# Flask-admin. Inlines form for items from postgres ARRAY

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Is there possible to create InlineForm for not model's related instances, but for array's items in the Flask-Admin?

example:

```
class Product(BaseModel):

__tablename__ = 'product'

id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
...
pictures = Column(sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY(String(255)), default=[])
```

I would like to create InlineForm with wtf.fields.FileField for each item in pictures. Unfortunately I can't find the way for create inlines without SQLA related model.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no - I didn't found solution